# A polynomial with positive integer powers is being displayed as a transcedental function (LerchPhi)

Tags: function-construction, polynomials

I am defining a polynomial as follows:

```
g[x_, n_] := x^(n - 1) - \!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(i = 1\), \(n - 1\)]\((
\*FractionBox[\(2  i - 1\), \(i + n - 1\)] 
\*SuperscriptBox[\(x\), \(i - 1\)])\)\)
```

When I evaluate it, I get an unnecessarily complicated answer because of `n` appearing in the denominator of the summation:

```
In[38]:= g[x, n]

Out[38]= x^(-1 + 
  n) + (1/((-1 + x) x))(2 x - 2 x^n + x LerchPhi[x, 1, n] - 
   2 n x LerchPhi[x, 1, n] - x^2 LerchPhi[x, 1, n] + 
   2 n x^2 LerchPhi[x, 1, n] - x^n LerchPhi[x, 1, -1 + 2 n] + 
   2 n x^n LerchPhi[x, 1, -1 + 2 n] + 
   x^(1 + n) LerchPhi[x, 1, -1 + 2 n] - 
   2 n x^(1 + n) LerchPhi[x, 1, -1 + 2 n])
```

I simply want my input to be shown with the summation expanded.

How should I define my function to prevent this? I want to perform symbolic computations on the polynomial later on, so I need `n` as a variable. I tried using `Assuming`, `Simplify`, and `FullSimplify` to no avail.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "input to be shown with the summation expanded"? Can you add an example?

Comment: Use e.g. `Table[ g[x, n], {n, 20}] // Column` otherwise there are no simpler expressions than `g[x,n]` assuming `n` is in a symbolic form.

Answer (score 1):

```
g[x_, n_?IntegerQ] := 
 x^(n - 1) - Sum[((2 i - 1)/(i + n - 1) x^(i - 1)), {i, 1, n - 1}]

g[x, 3]
g[x, n]
g[x, n] /. n -> 3
```

---

```
-(1/3) - (3 x)/4 + x^2

g[x, n]

-(1/3) - (3 x)/4 + x^2
```

Or use instead `g[x_, n_ /; n ∈ PositiveIntegers]` to limit  to only positive integers.

Answer (score 1):

What happens is that Mathematica is actually able to explicitly compute your series, which seems to contain two instances of `LerchPhi` (after you do `FullSimplify`).

Obviously, Mathematica cannot "expand" the series into separate terms for a symbolic $n$, but you can not let it calculate the series and preserving the `Sum` notation by using [`Inactivate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inactivate.html) (or [`Inactive`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inactive.html)):

```
Clear[g]
g[x_, n_] := x^(n - 1) - Inactivate[Sum[((2*i - 1)/(i + n - 1))*x^(i - 1), {i, 1, n - 1}], Sum]
(* or *)
g[x_, n_] := x^(n - 1) - Inactive[Sum][((2*i - 1)/(i + n - 1))*x^(i - 1), {i, 1, n - 1}]
```

`Sum` will now be preserved, and you can [`Activate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Activate.html) it at need.

```
g[x, n]
(* x^(-1 + n) - Inactive[Sum][((-1 + 2 i) x^(-1 + i))/(-1 + i + n), {i, 1, -1 + n}] *)

g[x, 2]
(* x - Inactive[Sum][((-1 + 2 i) x^(-1 + i))/(1 + i), {i, 1, 1}] *)
% // Activate
(* -(1/2) + x *)
```

Comment: This is almost perfect. I can even differentiate the `g[x,n]` which is great. But I cannot integrate it. Any suggestions to perform general operations on `g[x,n]`?

Comment: Maybe there are some more general approaches. But for this particular case, you can manually distribute the integral and also change the order of summation/integration: `Distribute[Integrate[g[x, n], x]] /. Integrate[Inactive[Sum][f_, i_], x_] :> Inactive[Sum][Integrate[f, x], i]`